# Android image downloading

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I want to download an image to my android phone and to follow the downloading  prossess   .
Well the downloading is working ,but i didn't found a way how tho follow it in log tag==> well my final target is to determine the speed of the download
like :

```
`at T=0,1s 40byte downloaded`
 at T=10s 2000byt downloaded ...
```

here is my code ,I hope someone will help me ,and thank you

```
public class DownloadActivity extends Activity {

    private MenuItem item;
    private String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/TestAndroid/DownloadServlet";
    //http://localhost:8080/TestAndroid/DownloadServlet/logo.png
    private String name = "/logo.png";      
    ImageView imgView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);

        imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView1);
        String[] params = new String[] {url, name};

        SendHttpRequestTask task = new SendHttpRequestTask();
        task.execute(params);
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        item = menu.getItem(0);
        return true;
    }


    private class SendHttpRequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, byte[]> {





        @Override
        protected byte[] doInBackground(String... params) {

            String url = params[0];
            String name = params[1];
            Log.i("log_tagaaaa",url );
            Log.i("log_tagaaaaa",name );


            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = null;
            String urlString =url+name;
            Log.v("Hub", "url"+urlString);
            String __url=urlString.replace(" ", "%20");
            HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet(__url);
            httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
            httpGet.setHeader("Accept-Language", "fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
            httpGet.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
            httpGet.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.0.1; en-us; GT-P7100 Build/HRI83) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.13");

            try {  
                response = client.execute(httpGet);
                //tableau d'octets en mémoire
                 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    InputStream in ;
                    in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {

                        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                        long total =0;
                        String d;
                        long a;
                        //le telechargement
                        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        int i =0 ;
                        while ( in.read(b) != -1)
                            {
                            baos.write(b);   
                            a= response.getEntity().getContentLength();
                            d=a+"";
                             Log.i("log_tag_taille",d );

                            }
                        // bytes_so_far : Number of bytes download so far.
                        //COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR : public static final String
                        String      bytes_so_far =  DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR ;
                         Log.i("log_tag_download",DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR  );



                        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                         // a= b.length;   


                        Log.i("log_tag_startTime",startTime +"" ); 
                        Log.i("log_tag_endTime",endTime +"" ); 
                        Log.i("log_tag_difference",endTime-startTime +"" ); 
                                    HashMap<String, Object> returnhashmap =new HashMap<String, Object>();




                    } else {


                        return null ;
                    }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // getContentLength va me donner la taille totale du fichier téléchargé 
            //returnhashmap.put(LENGTH_BUFFER, new Long(response.getEntity().getContentLength()));

            return null ;
}
         protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress) {
             super.onProgressUpdate(progress[0]);  
              Log.i("Progress Update: " , progress[0].toString());



            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(byte[] result) {
            Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result, 0, result.length);
            String d=result.length + "";
            Log.i("log_tagaaaaa onPostExecute",d ); 
            imgView.setImageBitmap(img);

            item.setActionView(null);

        }



    }


}
```

Comment: change the `while ( in.read(b) != -1)` to `while ( (n=in.read(b)) != -1)`, declare `int n;` before `while` loop. i think `n/100` is the speed. but i am not sure, because i haven't done it before. you can check it

Comment: yes thak you :) you are right , i just tried it  :)

Comment: i'll post the response at 3/10/2014 5:12:43 PM

Comment: well like i said it worked for the download , now i'm working in the upload i used this tutorial http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/25/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server/#comment-11064 and the upload is working ,but i didn't found where do i get the speed ,as i did it in the download, thanks

Comment: you can check this: 
1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133116/how-to-get-upload-progress-while-uploading-data-from-byte-array-to-a-php-server

2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854555/android-http-upload-progress-for-urlencodedformentity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a little serche i found a solution I had to change the loop while like Shoshi said,
 [I also recommand this tutorial :](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/#disqus_thread)

And this is the while loop that i changed from the tutrial ,according to my needs :`

```
while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    total += count;
                    long endtTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long passed;
                    passedTime =endtTime - startTotalTime;
                  //  passed=passedTime -previosTime ;
                   // previosTime = passed ;

                    // publishing the progress....
                    // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                    publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                    Log.i("log_lenghtOfFile",lenghtOfFile+"" );
                    Log.i("log_total",total+"" );
                    Log.i("log_ourcentage",(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile)+"" );
                    Log.i("log_passed_time",passedTime +"" );
                   // Log.i("log_Debit",passedTime +"" );
                    // writing data to file
                  //  output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
                long endTotalTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Log.i("log_Total_passed_time",endTotalTime-startTotalTime +"" );`
```

I hope it will help someone :)